How can I solve the issue of insufficient memory when dealing with large tuples?
How can I solve the issue of insufficient memory when dealing with large tuples?
For example,consider the following example:
Tuples[{1, 2, 3}, 25]



Until large quantum computers are available, there are at least 2 ways:  (1) Random sampling, and (2) determine the symbolic solution for your objective.  If you have something specific, maybe someone here can figure out a symbolic solution.

You are asking for a result that might take around 28 TERABYTES of space to store, never mind the time it would take to generate it... You need a different approach altogether.

RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {10, 25}] Change 10 to any number your computer can handle. Almost zero chance to get extreme cases such as {1,1,1,1,......,1,1,1}. Million sample in couple of second. RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {1000000, 25}]

Thank all. I need to cycle all permutation so I'll need a different approach.
@MarcoB could you share how you calculated required memory space?

@internet This may be innacurate for large lists, but it looks like on average, each additional tuple adds 200 bytes to the ByteCount: ByteCount /@ Table[RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {i, 25}], {i, 2000}] //     Differences // Mean // N (*200.02*)
multiplying that by the number of tuples (3^25) gives about 1.7*10^14 B (so 17 TB using 1TB = 10^12 B). I have no idea how accurate this is though, because I really don't know a lot about how large arrays of integers are stored in memory here.

@ydd Thanks! Rough estimation is enough.
